# expo-notifications not asking the user to accept notifications

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

Basically I'm using the "expo-notifications" lib to send notifications, it works well when I accept notifications from the app myself, but when the user doesn't have, the apllication can't ask the user to do it, the "Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();" doesn't open the prompt.

I read everything in this documentation: [expo-notifications-documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/) and still not working. I uploaded my project in github so you guys can see: [github project](https://github.com/valentimcanejo/notify) , I simply created a project with expo and put the expo-notifications example there, and still doesn't work, I'm really getting frustrated, help me please.
I've tried eveythinng I saw here and in other forums.